# Crash Report - iOS - Loads, But Crashes on First Touch

Tags: ios, crash-reports

Can anyone help me understand a crash report? I have just updated the app and all of a sudden it seems to be crash when you touch ANY button on the first view controller, but I have made no changes to the code regarding this but all of a sudden it is starting to cause problems. Any guidance on where to start would be amazing.

```
    Incident Identifier: EF8306B7-7714-4089-849B-CEE1BB721392
CrashReporter Key:   69f07ddbd44f2b41931a1c0cbe3a2bba5b94fd86
Hardware Model:      iPad2,5
Process:         ******** [895]
Path:            /var/mobile/Applications/FEA3E6BF-5A33-40F9-AB10-8F53DFAED64D/******** HD.app/iWhovian HD
Identifier:      ***************
Version:         ??? (???)
Code Type:       ARM (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [1]

Date/Time:       2013-06-10 16:54:27.884 +0100
OS Version:      iOS 6.1.3 (10B329)
Report Version:  104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Crashed Thread:  0

Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                  0x3404029e __exceptionPreprocess + 158
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x3beeb97a objc_exception_throw + 26
2   CoreFoundation                  0x340401c0 +[NSException raise:format:] + 100
3   Foundation                      0x348b5104 -[NSURL(NSURL) initFileURLWithPath:] + 72
4   Foundation                      0x348b502e +[NSURL(NSURL) fileURLWithPath:] + 38
5   iWhovian HD                     0x000fd03c -[MainViewController clicksound] (MainViewController.m:53)
6   iWhovian HD                     0x000fd478 -[MainViewController playbuttonClicked] (MainViewController.m:116)
7   UIKit                           0x35f330c0 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 68
8   UIKit                           0x35f33072 -[UIApplication sendAction:toTarget:fromSender:forEvent:] + 26
9   UIKit                           0x35f33050 -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 40
10  UIKit                           0x35f32906 -[UIControl(Internal) _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 498
11  UIKit                           0x35f32dfc -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 484
12  UIKit                           0x35e5b5ec -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 520
13  UIKit                           0x35e487fc -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 376
14  UIKit                           0x35e48116 _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 6150
15  GraphicsServices                0x37b5359e _PurpleEventCallback + 586
16  GraphicsServices                0x37b531ce PurpleEventCallback + 30
17  CoreFoundation                  0x3401516e __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 30
18  CoreFoundation                  0x34015112 __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 134
19  CoreFoundation                  0x34013f94 __CFRunLoopRun + 1380
20  CoreFoundation                  0x33f86eb8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 352
21  CoreFoundation                  0x33f86d44 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 100
22  GraphicsServices                0x37b522e6 GSEventRunModal + 70
23  UIKit                           0x35e9c2fc UIApplicationMain + 1116
24  iWhovian HD                     0x000f5b62 main (main.m:16)
25  iWhovian HD                     0x000f5b24 start + 36


Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3c3e9350 __pthread_kill + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3c36011e pthread_kill + 54
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3c39c96e abort + 90
3   libc++abi.dylib                 0x3b93ad4a abort_message + 70
4   libc++abi.dylib                 0x3b937ff4 default_terminate() + 20
5   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x3beeba74 _objc_terminate() + 144
6   libc++abi.dylib                 0x3b938078 safe_handler_caller(void (*)()) + 76
7   libc++abi.dylib                 0x3b938110 std::terminate() + 16
8   libc++abi.dylib                 0x3b939594 __cxa_rethrow + 84
9   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x3beeb9cc objc_exception_rethrow + 8
10  CoreFoundation                  0x33f86f1c CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 452
11  CoreFoundation                  0x33f86d44 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 100
12  GraphicsServices                0x37b522e6 GSEventRunModal + 70
13  UIKit                           0x35e9c2fc UIApplicationMain + 1116
14  iWhovian HD                     0x000f5b62 main (main.m:16)
15  iWhovian HD                     0x000f5b24 start + 36

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3c3e9d98 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3c337cf6 _pthread_workq_return + 14
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3c337a12 _pthread_wqthread + 362
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3c3378a0 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 2 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3c3d9648 kevent64 + 24
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x3c309974 _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 792
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x3c309654 _dispatch_mgr_thread$VARIANT$mp + 32

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3c3e9d98 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3c337cf6 _pthread_workq_return + 14
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3c337a12 _pthread_wqthread + 362
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3c3378a0 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 4 name:  WebThread
Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3c3d8eb4 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3c3d9048 mach_msg + 36
2   CoreFoundation                  0x34015040 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 124
3   CoreFoundation                  0x34013d9e __CFRunLoopRun + 878
4   CoreFoundation                  0x33f86eb8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 352
5   CoreFoundation                  0x33f86d44 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 100
6   WebCore                         0x39f8d500 RunWebThread(void*) + 440
7   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3c34230e _pthread_start + 306
8   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3c3421d4 thread_start + 4

Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3c3e9d98 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3c337cf6 _pthread_workq_return + 14
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3c337a12 _pthread_wqthread + 362
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3c3378a0 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 6 name:  AQClient
Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3c3d8eb4 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3c3d9048 mach_msg + 36
2   CoreFoundation                  0x34015040 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 124
3   CoreFoundation                  0x34013d9e __CFRunLoopRun + 878
4   CoreFoundation                  0x33f86eb8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 352
5   CoreFoundation                  0x33f86d44 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 100
6   AudioToolbox                    0x33a686fe GenericRunLoopThread::Entry(void*) + 134
7   AudioToolbox                    0x33a49882 CAPThread::Entry(CAPThread*) + 294
8   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3c34230e _pthread_start + 306
9   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3c3421d4 thread_start + 4

Thread 7:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3c3e9d98 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3c337cf6 _pthread_workq_return + 14
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3c337a12 _pthread_wqthread + 362
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3c3378a0 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (32-bit):
    r0: 0x00000000    r1: 0x00000000      r2: 0x00000000      r3: 0x3dedf534
    r4: 0x00000006    r5: 0x3dedfb88      r6: 0x1fdb9714      r7: 0x2fd0da24
    r8: 0x1fdb96f0    r9: 0x00000400     r10: 0x00000000     r11: 0x00000001
    ip: 0x00000148    sp: 0x2fd0da18      lr: 0x3c360123      pc: 0x3c3e9350
  cpsr: 0x00000010

Binary Images:
   0xf3000 -   0x10dfff +iWhovian HD armv7  <53cc16be6b9e3b30b6b8925fc77f0249> /var/mobile/Applications/FEA3E6BF-5A33-40F9-AB10-8F53DFAED64D/iWhovian HD.app/iWhovian HD
0x2fe8b000 - 0x2feabfff  dyld armv7  <280610df5ed43ec7aa00629a27009302> /usr/lib/dyld
0x33161000 - 0x33247fff  AVFoundation armv7  <320761e836883aeabf3cb5c53edb636d> /System/Library/Frameworks/AVFoundation.framework/AVFoundation
0x33248000 - 0x33248fff  Accelerate armv7  <b68ff92e404931f3bcb6361720f77724> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Accelerate
0x33249000 - 0x33387fff  vImage armv7  <30522b92940d3dd184c8e46780594048> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vImage.framework/vImage
0x33388000 - 0x3346bfff  libBLAS.dylib armv7  <d8edada1cea133458ca779e34a3a7f88> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libBLAS.dylib
0x3346c000 - 0x33721fff  libLAPACK.dylib armv7  <9e08aead79d13043bab622402a270fba> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libLAPACK.dylib
0x33722000 - 0x3377bfff  libvDSP.dylib armv7  <09e2a5e3e9203950890ba57592523132> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libvDSP.dylib
0x3377c000 - 0x3378dfff  libvMisc.dylib armv7  <7b7d4ccc9f2b364cb0da4251e745545d> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libvMisc.dylib
0x3378e000 - 0x3378efff  vecLib armv7  <a7751c047dcc35ba8885212e1938b93f> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/vecLib
0x3378f000 - 0x337a0fff  Accounts armv7  <ea2de358b6cc3baab27d6ab809c31e39> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accounts.framework/Accounts
0x337a1000 - 0x337a1fff  AdSupport armv7  <583bf32d959735949952a2595c86ed20> /System/Library/Frameworks/AdSupport.framework/AdSupport
0x337a2000 - 0x33806fff  AddressBook armv7  <8cfae84dc66d3c1f9d17335c53c3d7b7> /System/Library/Frameworks/AddressBook.framework/AddressBook
0x33807000 - 0x338c1fff  AddressBookUI armv7  <0017d0a0c2593522acaaa0eee41775e4> /System/Library/Frameworks/AddressBookUI.framework/AddressBookUI
0x338c2000 - 0x338d0fff  AssetsLibrary armv7  <9a3a4a47a77833eb82a28757a3488660> /System/Library/Frameworks/AssetsLibrary.framework/AssetsLibrary
0x33a0c000 - 0x33c94fff  AudioToolbox armv7  <394ee11cf826367db9ff4968dbc71d6d> /System/Library/Frameworks/AudioToolbox.framework/AudioToolbox
0x33c95000 - 0x33d5afff  CFNetwork armv7  <4771a5e4f9b83bceb252f0f3d166aaca> /System/Library/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework/CFNetwork
0x33d5b000 - 0x33db1fff  CoreAudio armv7  <5d534dbf76ff30f4a628f25f56c5f26a> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreAudio.framework/CoreAudio
0x33dc5000 - 0x33f7dfff  CoreData armv7  <3930f672c76535a2abb768ee59958fa7> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreData.framework/CoreData
0x33f7e000 - 0x340b0fff  CoreFoundation armv7  <fcb8d4e838543bcb9a52c9f232b8b4eb> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
0x340b1000 - 0x341e9fff  CoreGraphics armv7  <81e213f810a034d4ba411f9b505da2a6> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/CoreGraphics
0x341eb000 - 0x34226fff  libCGFreetype.A.dylib armv7  <a5d20b80ab1532d8831027a66d2d9eb5> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Resources/libCGFreetype.A.dylib
0x3440a000 - 0x34425fff  libRIP.A.dylib armv7  <ec1487f9bdb93597a3f8d434406ad9bf> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Resources/libRIP.A.dylib
0x34426000 - 0x344dbfff  CoreImage armv7  <6ae4ae2461313e3f84c6a8102d5b1b0e> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreImage.framework/CoreImage
0x344dc000 - 0x34534fff  CoreLocation armv7  <4edb4b0f05e13af8b84699fe3ea4c538> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreLocation.framework/CoreLocation
0x34569000 - 0x345cefff  CoreMedia armv7  <8592bdc268b83b8886acfc1fdab649ed> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreMedia.framework/CoreMedia
0x345cf000 - 0x34657fff  CoreMotion armv7  <4512d901170d32e7842e7fc1c519386b> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreMotion.framework/CoreMotion
0x34658000 - 0x346aefff  CoreTelephony armv7  <bea09dbe25363c3b8e8016b5b5148055> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreTelephony.framework/CoreTelephony
0x346af000 - 0x34711fff  CoreText armv7  <e135debbc8f937299f4986fc3e9459e3> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreText.framework/CoreText
0x34712000 - 0x34721fff  CoreVideo armv7  <00f18bb26e663da9ae251a6ec36a19ec> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreVideo.framework/CoreVideo
0x34722000 - 0x347d6fff  EventKit armv7  <99a7a1603323319f9e24f97e9f89bfd3> /System/Library/Frameworks/EventKit.framework/EventKit
0x348a6000 - 0x34a69fff  Foundation armv7  <0179934581d13346aa7583165108b95c> /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation
0x34ab4000 - 0x34c23fff  GameKit armv7  <7958b5418ef230d38dc0cf754b2a782b> /System/Library/Frameworks/GameKit.framework/GameKit
0x34c24000 - 0x34c6dfff  IOKit armv7  <a98ba9fefc7333e4a5a9169198848c62> /System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/Versions/A/IOKit
0x34c6e000 - 0x34e46fff  ImageIO armv7  <b5ce84bb074d3de4b07b55da9fd8bfd1> /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/ImageIO
0x34ec0000 - 0x3505afff  MediaPlayer armv7  <ce97a30e514d3a17ae93ba4a9d1d69d2> /System/Library/Frameworks/MediaPlayer.framework/MediaPlayer
0x3505b000 - 0x352d5fff  MediaToolbox armv7  <ed439fc5c9a03f8b9fae43af33de8a57> /System/Library/Frameworks/MediaToolbox.framework/MediaToolbox
0x352d6000 - 0x3535cfff  MessageUI armv7  <8dbc0a8e6a253c8c8d6301064f23dfea> /System/Library/Frameworks/MessageUI.framework/MessageUI
0x3535d000 - 0x353b6fff  MobileCoreServices armv7  <77da8a9e7f813f5baf37eaa4a87fae84> /System/Library/Frameworks/MobileCoreServices.framework/MobileCoreServices
0x354a5000 - 0x354acfff  OpenGLES armv7  <f2ede6b206f336de82cc38619692e762> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/OpenGLES
0x354ae000 - 0x354aefff  libCVMSPluginSupport.dylib armv7  <2506af1c983f3f09ac69aca44f67e863> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libCVMSPluginSupport.dylib
0x354b2000 - 0x354b4fff  libCoreVMClient.dylib armv7  <af6ff28dce6031baaa850ccc79e5699b> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libCoreVMClient.dylib
0x354b5000 - 0x354b9fff  libGFXShared.dylib armv7  <a6ac1673a088379aa512ba5cac301f5b> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGFXShared.dylib
0x354ba000 - 0x354f7fff  libGLImage.dylib armv7  <b8b8f3a1bfd0345e86aa0c2952534949> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGLImage.dylib
0x35bf2000 - 0x35d07fff  QuartzCore armv7  <c086b6e6cd9d341399bcc3675c82f1fe> /System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/QuartzCore
0x35d08000 - 0x35d55fff  QuickLook armv7  <954e3a8bdaf337b085b30fd514ea5f3a> /System/Library/Frameworks/QuickLook.framework/QuickLook
0x35d56000 - 0x35d84fff  Security armv7  <fbc24f15bd9e37539cdd6e3576bde938> /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Security
0x35d85000 - 0x35df2fff  Social armv7  <7b778c6ce3433df18ef0892acd831208> /System/Library/Frameworks/Social.framework/Social
0x35df3000 - 0x35e02fff  StoreKit armv7  <e63a14831d2d315ba5cf654102d67f8c> /System/Library/Frameworks/StoreKit.framework/StoreKit
0x35e03000 - 0x35e42fff  SystemConfiguration armv7  <410d69b356e533d6a1d538cf33059634> /System/Library/Frameworks/SystemConfiguration.framework/SystemConfiguration
0x35e43000 - 0x35e44fff  Twitter armv7  <ecae25ed2c893a969ceb0b911420c2be> /System/Library/Frameworks/Twitter.framework/Twitter
0x35e45000 - 0x36399fff  UIKit armv7  <ad8b3ad23f413187a178179db39cfa6b> /System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIKit
0x3639a000 - 0x363d8fff  VideoToolbox armv7  <d2e8067306d9346ab4a448f10f336894> /System/Library/Frameworks/VideoToolbox.framework/VideoToolbox
0x36661000 - 0x3666dfff  AccountSettings armv7  <8db45acc4d3d3017af10fa5ee82c2306> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AccountSettings.framework/AccountSettings
0x366b4000 - 0x366b7fff  ActorKit armv7  <5dfc59258ea63006be9c542e5fafbc45> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ActorKit.framework/ActorKit
0x366b9000 - 0x366bcfff  AggregateDictionary armv7  <c2a6c1ff89a9318d8b74fc5dfc8847b8> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AggregateDictionary.framework/AggregateDictionary
0x367a5000 - 0x367b8fff  AirTraffic armv7  <752b64045f4d3ea88a946b53b731ce1a> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AirTraffic.framework/AirTraffic
0x36ae8000 - 0x36b23fff  AppSupport armv7  <921794b7d82a3558a0eb860979be199c> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppSupport.framework/AppSupport
0x36b24000 - 0x36b48fff  AppleAccount armv7  <c54536fbc0f235f693060be33d4d4749> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppleAccount.framework/AppleAccount
0x36b55000 - 0x36b62fff  ApplePushService armv7  <8bad4a9300db3d4d8555535f25c32da4> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ApplePushService.framework/ApplePushService
0x36b96000 - 0x36b9ffff  AssetsLibraryServices armv7  <de7ca29cd47433cd8eca9c04102f5508> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AssetsLibraryServices.framework/AssetsLibraryServices
0x36ba0000 - 0x36bb9fff  AssistantServices armv7  <9608ae74229e3daeab9c8fcf679de7d4> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AssistantServices.framework/AssistantServices
0x36bcf000 - 0x36be6fff  BackBoardServices armv7  <772912697ec23e5199a452e97f075dd9> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/BackBoardServices.framework/BackBoardServices
0x36be9000 - 0x36beffff  BluetoothManager armv7  <fe002961c52538eb8c959e7c1c58467a> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/BluetoothManager.framework/BluetoothManager
0x36bf0000 - 0x36c14fff  Bom armv7  <b5315d733e123a0781683efdc734064b> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Bom.framework/Bom
0x36c27000 - 0x36c56fff  BulletinBoard armv7  <9f46015c5d263064901f7725f4bb93e0> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/BulletinBoard.framework/BulletinBoard
0x36c94000 - 0x36c9bfff  CaptiveNetwork armv7  <a4f4b86cc84839f78ff746f013bcee6f> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CaptiveNetwork.framework/CaptiveNetwork
0x36c9c000 - 0x36d66fff  Celestial armv7  <a688df527b65382da586ebc87f28c061> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Celestial.framework/Celestial
0x36d73000 - 0x36d77fff  CertUI armv7  <ce979f715cdb3cb5a0f7935f14cc0b35> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CertUI.framework/CertUI
0x36e1d000 - 0x36e36fff  ChunkingLibrary armv7  <ec2f76b3ac723a39bbf3f122d7fe73cf> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ChunkingLibrary.framework/ChunkingLibrary
0x36e4a000 - 0x36e4ffff  CommonUtilities armv7  <f8fea9ee6ca236b0a7fa6c00eb8a0d24> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CommonUtilities.framework/CommonUtilities
0x36ed4000 - 0x36f04fff  ContentIndex armv7  <00ed488e47ee34ca9f01f2cc911f453c> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ContentIndex.framework/ContentIndex
0x36f80000 - 0x37068fff  CoreMediaStream armv7  <828bf27fe7a3337cbff7dd8837508819> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreMediaStream.framework/CoreMediaStream
0x37115000 - 0x37116fff  CoreSurface armv7  <6065f7e040e93d6ea2837e929592cc30> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreSurface.framework/CoreSurface
0x3717e000 - 0x37182fff  CoreTime armv7  <5f0b123555f03d8aa76cc54314907942> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreTime.framework/CoreTime
0x37183000 - 0x37188fff  CrashReporterSupport armv7  <03ee46e3ca3f3920a7174e62096723fb> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CrashReporterSupport.framework/CrashReporterSupport
0x37189000 - 0x371c5fff  DataAccess armv7  <d7185042adf63908ae87fe4a5c3f8a6c> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataAccess.framework/DataAccess
0x3735a000 - 0x3736cfff  DataAccessExpress armv7  <b9423867a9ef303b87d2e1eac1712957> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataAccessExpress.framework/DataAccessExpress
0x373ab000 - 0x373acfff  DataMigration armv7  <5903e08348b83f119022cbbf83ad100a>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is in  `clicksound` Method of `MainViewController` at `line number 53`. I think crash occurs in when you create `NSURL` check that code.

Comment: Thank you so much how obvious was that. The TapSound.wav file was missing from my project so it was crashing when it was trying to find it to play it.